# Are Authenticated Users required to be added to NTFS permissions for shared folder?

Tags: ntfs, shared-folders, windows-server-2019

I am using Server 2019 and am trying to create a shared folder. But I want only certain users to have access to it.
So, based on my knowledge (and quick online search), I created a Global Security in my AD and added those users to it. Then I created a folder to be shared. Gave Share permission to "Everyone" and for NTFS permissions, I disabled inheritance and added the security group and Domain admins.

The problem is, when I map the drive for the users (via GPO), the users added to the group cannot access the shared folder unless I add "Authenticated Users" group to the NTFS permissions.
The only other way they can access the folder is if I added them directly to the NTFS permission.

My question is, is Auth Users group required for NTFS? If so, wouldn't that allow access to basically all users? And if that's the case, then I won't be able to restrict the users from accessing the shared drive.

Comment: so you shouldn't have to use that group for most purposes, as "DomainUsers" or "Everyone" will usually cover all the bases,  but if you have local non-built-in users you will need to grant this group, or add the users directly.  Last time i needed to use it was in 2006 or so when working on an app for remote disconnected users that only occasionally connected to the VPN. I forget why precisely it was required, but it won't be a normal thing.

Comment: So, that's the thing. I don't want all domain users to have access to this folder, only certain users, hence the need of group. But even when I add this group with Full Control permissions, the users can't seem to access the folder. It says "Access has been denied to the destination folder."

Comment: in your GPO, did you enable the setting "Run in logged on users’s security context"?